# Sending datas by chunk

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

in C, I have to send a bunch of datas with tcp/ip (~6.5mo)
I'm using the "classic" send().
Do you think it's a good idea to give to the function the whole size of data to send in one part or should I prefer the chunk way (slices of, for example, 64ko...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it the full size, and just call it again with the rest of the buffer (according to the return value).

You deal with your logic, let the OS deal with the send logic.

Comment: Especially considering that you canot pass 6Mb in a single call to `send()` anyway, so let the OS handle the chunking for you.  Just pass as much data as you can, and let `send()` tell you how much it actually accepted, then just resend whatever is left over, repeating as needed until all of the data is finished.